# Does shrinking a partition to its minimum size then expanding it increase performance?

Tags: partitioning, performance, ext3

As a VPS administrator, I've shrunken and cloned partitions (or disk images) to perform backups.  The shrinking of the partition adds a few extra minutes of downtime, but reduces the amount of total space used towards the quota.  This shrunken partition is then cloned, and the original partition is expanded to its normal production size before the server is restarted.

It is my understanding that the underlying `resize2fs` command moves files as required to shrink the partition, which has the effect of defragmenting (or at least consolidating files on) the volume.  Does this operation increase performance?

Comment: yes, on ext FS, moving files out and back to a partition does have the same effect of defragmenting.

Comment: Files are not being moved out of the partition.  Files are being moved *within* the partition.

Comment: then my guess is no.